# Python ldap3 connection fails when django app is deployed on ecs, but not on local

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I have a django api that streams data from an Active directory source and processes it. My connection looks something like this

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection

        
server = Server(url, get_info=ALL)

conn = Connection(server, username, password, auto_bind=True)
```

I put this app on a container, the dockerfile is simple and looks like this

```
FROM python:3.9

EXPOSE 8002
# Install Dependencies   
ADD requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . .
CMD ./server.sh
```

Server.sh is also fairly simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
aws s3 cp s3://some_creds .

python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

Now, on local, and on gitpod this connection has no issues. I go on to do searches on the conn without problems. However, when I deploy the same container on ecs via ecr I was running on local, I get this error:

> <class 'ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPSocketOpenError'>, LDAPSocketOpenError('socket connection error while opening: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'), ('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', xxx))])

This may be a side effect of accessing the api from ssl, but if that is the case, I simply cannot replicate it on locale.

This error occurs only on POST requests; any other request goes through as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the *Active Directory* being only accessible via vpn/proxy. The gitpod instance I was using was company provided so it also had network access to the AD.

This was solved by using a VPC that had default access to this network.